# Get xi:include to work for log4j

Tags: xml, include, log4j, slf4j

I am really interested in using the xi:include feature in log4j but I cannot seem to get this example to work (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-341). I am using Log4j 2.0.1 (specifically log4j-api-2.0.1.jar, log4j-core-2.0.1.jar and log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.1.jar).

The issue is this line:

```
<configuration xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
           status="warn" name="XMLConfigTest" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.test">
```

My IDE (intellij) comes up with the error "cannot find the declaration of element 'configuration' "

I do not really know where I am going wrong.